# Add borderless search buttons in UINavigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

Good morning, good evening !

I feel like my question is a dumb easy to solve question, but it looks like `Google` can't help me.

I want to add on my `UINavigationBar` a search button, but I want it borderless !

When I set it through `Xcode` I have this awful kind of button :

[image: Button with border]

And I want this kind of button (from the `Dropbox app`) :
[image: Button without border]

That would be nice if someone is able to explain me the trick to achieve this !

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a bar button item. I have played around with it. And the Bar Buttom Item has to have a Tint of Clear Color. The actual Button a Type of Custom. Then it comes out more the way you want it (I think).

In my IB it looks like this:

[image]

It is the following

[image]

With properties like this:

[image]

And like this:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Interface Builder set the button type to custom and use your image as background for the button.